# Salesman, company monopoly, robotic competitor, razor blades

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I read this story in an anthology several years ago I think it was either a robot anthology or a salesman is sci-fi/fantasy anthology

A man is teleported (I think) to a planet to explore it for a company, he is happy because the pay is really good but then he realizes that the company has the sole monopoly on resupplying him and they charge exorbitant fees for even the smallest things (I think razor blades are mentioned somewhere)

A robot appears from somewhere and starts trying to sell him stuff thats better than the company provides and at cheaper prices the company is understandably upset about this and threaten him with breach of contract

thats pretty much all I got

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds to me like [Company Store](http://www.majipoor.com/work.php?id=177) by Robert Silverberg. The story has been in lots of anthologies.

Comment: yeah that was it, thanks