# Old story where a colonist is sent by a company to colonise a new planet where he meets a robot

Tags: story-identification

Science fiction story where a colonist is sent by a company to colonize a planet and there a robot tries to sell him a depilating liquid by pulling a gun on him. The company who sponsored his trip to the new planet is extorting him by charging him exorbitant rates for anything they declare is not considered by them as bare necessities. The robot and man collaborate to get from the company the fair deal he deserves.

Comment: Do you mean "depilating" liquid?  (i.e. hair removal liquid)

Comment: (This sounds like something that Kornbluth might have written.)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36130/salesman-company-monopoly-robotic-competitor-razor-blades

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Company Store by Robert Silverberg](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58605).

> “Pardon me, sir,” said a familiar sharp voice. “I happened to overhear that order for razor blades, and I think it’s only fair to inform you that I carry a product of much greater face-appeal.”
>
> Wingert was on his feet in an instant, glaring at the robot. “I told you to go away. A-W-A-Y.”
>
> Undisturbed, the robot produced a small translucent tube filled with a glossy green paste. “This,” XL-ad41 said, “is Gloglam’s Depilating Fluid, twelve units—ah, one dollar, that is—per tube.”
>
> Wingert shook his head. “I get my goods free, from Terra. Besides, I like to shave with a razor. Please go away.”
>
> The robot looked about as crestfallen as a robot could possibly look. “You don’t seem to understand that your refusal to purchase from me reflects adversely on my abilities, and may result in my being dismantled at the end of this test. Therefore I insist you approach my merchandise with an open mind.”
>
> A sudden grin of salesman-like inspiration illuminated XL-ad41’s face. “I’ll take the liberty of offering you this free sample. Try Gloglam’s Depilating Fluid and I can guarantee you’ll never use a blade-razor again.”
>
> The robot poured a small quantity of the green fluid into a smaller vial and handed it to Wingert. “Here. I’ll return shortly to hear your decision.”

It's later in the story that the robot uses the gun:

> “Try somewhere else, then. Find a planet full of suckers and give ‘em the hard sell. I can’t buy from you.”
>
> “I’m afraid you’ll have to,” the robot said mildly. “My specifications call for me to return to Densobol for inspection after my seventeenth visit.” A panel in the robot’s abdomen opened whirringly and Wingert saw the snout of a Molecular Disruptor emerge.

The company are exploiting their exploration staff by charging reasonable prices for the goods they supply but charging exhorbitant shipping rates. For example when Wingert buys some razor blades the blades cost 23 cents but there's a 50 dollar shipping charge (this was in 1959 when $50 was a lot).

> Wingert stared moodily at the shiny tips of his boots. The Company, he thought, had him sewed up neatly. He had no money and no way of returning to Earth short of dividing himself into three equal chunks and teleporting. And though Quellac was an attractive planet, it lacked certain aspects of Earth. Tobacco, for one. Wingert enjoyed smoking.
>
> A box of cigars would be $2.40 plus $75 shipping-costs. And Smathers would smirk and tell him cigars were luxuries.

In the end:

> Wingert quits the company and goes into partnership with the robot.